Comparing Models with Unequal Sample Sizes
I have performed an association analysis where I have associatiated several different perdictor variables to a dependent variable. For each predictor, I run two models and compare them via the likelihood ratio test. The first model controls for the effect of time, the second model is time alone. Here is how my modeling strategy looks:
Phenotype 1
model1 <- Y ~ phenotype1 + Time + (1|RE)
model2 <- Y ~ Time + (1|RE)
anova(model1, model2, test = "LRT")
Phenotype 2
model3 <- Y ~ phenotype2 + Time + (1|RE)
model4 <- Y ~ Time + (1|RE)
anova(model3, model4, test = "LRT")
Phenotype 3
model5 <- Y ~ phenotype2 + Time + (1|RE)
model6 <- Y ~ Time + (1|RE)
anova(model5, model6, test = "LRT")
I am particularly interested in what phenotype best explains my dependent variable (N.B., Y is the same for all models). Also, I am not interested in what combination of phenotypes best fits Y, rather, what is the single best predictor of Y. Ideally what I would do is to take the models with the phenotype that are significant in the likelihood ratio test and then compare them via their AIC or likelihood. However, the problem is that due to phenotype sampling, each model has different sample sizes.
Thus, my question: how can I compare models of unequal sample sizes in order to see what phenotype best explains my dependent variable?
One idea I had was something like cross-validation, where I run the model on different subsets of my data. Thus, from each subset, which would have equal samples sizes across different models, I could calculate the AIC, take the average across all iterations, and then compare models based on the average AIC value. Also, each phenotype has a decent samples size (n > 100).

My first thought was also your "like cross-validation" approach, seems sound. One remark: you do NOT have the same Y data, because of the different sample sizes. I'm not sure if the Y data are partially equal, like the largest dataset containing the smaller ones?

What may hinder the comparison is the random effect. If you compare the likelihoods of just two equally sized samples but coming from different RE units, the likelihoods will be different because of these different RE's in both samples, which has nothing to do with how "good" your predictor is.

Apparently you cannot simply compare the b coefficients of the three phenotypes?

@BenP, thank you for your comments! Indeed, the Y data in each model will not be exactly the same. However, I have about 3000 samples total, so I can take robust subsets of data where the Y-values are shared.

Using exactly the same Y data for the three phenotypes will surely facilitate comparisons. You can then even simply compare the loglikelihoods, AIC not needed.

@BenP. Point 2: Random effects are the same for each model. Their origin is the individual from which Y was sampled over repeated measurments. Point 3: Perhaps this is a good approach. Keep in mind that Y is actually a latent variable where I was trying to make an association. As each latent variable should have an independent source of variation, I though a likelihood-based comparison with each predictor as a single model would be the best approach.

@BenP, thus when doing comparisons on the same Y-data, you would also suggest a sort of cross-validation approach?

Would there not be only one single sample then, which you then use for each phenotype? Maybe I'm understanding this wrong?

Yes, each sample (an individual) is characterized by many different phenotypes.

Sorry, I understood "sample" as "group of individuals". Thought you had one and the same group of inviduals to test the three phenotypes.

whups. i see i explained it wrong. each sample is from one individual. Thus at each time point there are samples are taken from different individuals and then repeated at the next time point. Thus our RE is at the "individual" level
